# How to display items in Canvas through Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have list of items that I want to display in Canvas using data binding.

```
ItemsToShowInCanvas = new ObservableCollection<ItemDetail>
   {
       new ItemDetail {Text = "ABC", Top = 10, Left = 200},
       new ItemDetail {Text = "DEF", Top = 100, Left = 300},
       new ItemDetail {Text = "PQR", Top = 50, Left = 150}
   };
```

ItemDetail is a simple class with auto properties for Text, Top and Left values

```
public class ItemDetail
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
    public double Left { get; set; }
}
```

When I databind the items, they do appear in canvas. But the items do not appear at positions mentioned using Top and Left properties.

```
<Canvas>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsToShowInCanvas}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Top}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Left}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: ItemsControl uses Stackpanel as default itemspanel. the textblock you are adding is actually adding to a stackpanel but not to canvas. The ItemsControl is adding to canvas. Try changing itemspanel to canvas

Comment: Thanks for the answer bathineni. I tried putting ItemsPanel as Canvas but it didnt work. The items started showing one over the other. Adding the ItemContainerStyle worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Is it possible to bind a Canvas's Children property in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml)

Comment: @H.B. Definetely duplicate. On the other hand, possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265364/setting-canvas-properties-in-an-itemscontrol-datatemplate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415580/when-using-itemscontrol-itemscontrol-itemspanel-is-set-to-canvas-contenpresenter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708151/how-to-convert-x-y-position-to-canvas-left-top-properties-when-using-itemscontrol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261640/how-can-i-position-viewmodels-in-an-itemscontrol. Feels like every question here has been answered at least 10 times :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set the `ItemsPanel` to a `Canvas` and bind the containers instead of the `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsToShowInCanvas}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: If I have a `Shape` instead of a `TextBlock` can I simply replace one with the other?

Comment: Also, where does the `ItemsControl` reside in the document tree?

Comment: ItemsControl.ItemsContainerStyle was just what I needed I have the rest working. Thank a bunch.