# Creating a chart for different Polygons C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, graph, charts

I have a `List<Geometry>` containing data from [Round Polygons](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128705/WPF-rounded-corners-polygon) and a `List<Rectangle>` where items will be added during runtime. I want to plot these data in a x-y-Chart at the bottom left position of my window. The output should look similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GpHS.png). The x- and y- axis should represent the angles in a round object.

I checked different approaches for charts and graphs like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32836/A-simple-C-library-for-graph-plotting) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32973/WPF-A-graph-control), but I couldn´t get a satisfying result.

Does anybody have an idea how this chart could be realised with WPF or knows where to look for examples which lead in a similar direction?

Comment: You could probably rig something up using an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as the container. Something like what is proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177432/how-to-display-items-in-canvas-through-binding) answer.

Comment: Best WPF free charts I found where [oxy](http://www.oxyplot.org/) if I understood the request you should be able to do it with them.